# My applications won't autostart when i run them on a device. Used to work until I updated to Android Studio 2.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm having trouble getting my apps to run in the emulator. I recently installed android studio 2.0 and now the apps wont run on the emulators. I never had a problem with it before. I tried to create a new project and there the app auto starts without a problem. Why does my app created in the previous version of Android Studio fail to start when starting the emulator?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be due to version conflicts, Try to check your Target SDK and Minimum SDK version in build.gradle file.

It should be compatible with your emulator api versions.
The issue has nothing to do with studio 2.0 , Try updating SDK with your project .:)